# Is it possible to trigger the bootstrap modal on onbeforeunload event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-modal

I want to trigger my bootstrap modal when user tries to close the browser. I am trying to do it with below code but doesn't seem to be working.

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(e){
    $('#myModal').modal('show');
}
```

If it is not possible then how can I trigger it on closing or clicking the back browser button?
    Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @ Kartikeya thanks for editing the code bro

Comment: I'm afraid that you can't. Even the facebook uses the native alert box, so imagine if they are not able to do it who will be?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Display modal form before user leaves page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3927904/display-modal-form-before-user-leaves-page)

Answer (score 0):

According to this page https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload You can't display modal instead prompt while reloading the page.